# MYSQL statement not working in Flask - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql, flask

my app.py file contains the MYSQL statements as well

```
@app.route("/stock",methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def stock():
    dat=date.today()
    # cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM stock")
    items = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
    orde = cursor.fetchone()
    order = int(orde["id"]+1)
    dump = json.dumps(items)
    total = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form.get("IO", False) or request.form["client"]=="Choose":
            flash("Please fill in or out radio buttons and Customer","danger")
        elif request.form["IO"] == "out":
            values = ['id','name','Out']
            record = [order,request.form["client"],True]
            abc = request.form["client"]
            query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = %s" 
            cursor.execute(query,[abc])
            customers = cursor.fetchone()
            for item in items:
                foo = int(request.form[item["name"]])
                values.append(item['name'])
                record.append(foo)
                if foo>int(item["stock"]):
                    flash("not enough stock","danger")
                    return redirect(url_for('stock'))
                sto=item["stock"]-foo
                minitotal = foo*item["price"]
                total = total + minitotal
                cursor.execute("UPDATE `stock` SET stock = %s WHERE (name = %s)",[sto,item["name"]])
            today = request.form["today"]
            values.append('Price')
            values.append('date')
            record.append(total)
            record.append(today)
            trecord = tuple(record)
            vrecord = tuple(values)
            query = "INSERT INTO orders {0} VALUES {1}"
            print(vrecord)
            cursor.execute(query.format(vrecord,trecord))  
            mydb.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('bill',client=abc))
...............
     return render_template('New_Order.html',items=items,customers=customerees,suppliers = suppliers,index=My_list,dump=dump,date=dat)
```

the error is this :

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id', 'name', 'Out', 'KSA4060', 'PAA003S', 'PAA003SS', 'Lapdesk', 'ASM704PH', 'L' at line 1

There is not a length problem here:
when I used a single tuple before the code worked but my values got messed up. so I added another tuple for the columns. the code stops working mid-word as you can see in the error statement.
the values are equal - below are the two tuples getting used

```
vrecord = ('id', 'name', 'Out', 'KSA4060', 'PAA003S', 'PAA003SS', 'Lapdesk', 'ASM704PH', 'LED4060', 'ASM820', 'ASM806', 'ASM823', 'ASM857C', 'KP3780', 'KX8680', 'KX8060', 'PA3550A', 'PA3550B', 'PA3550AS', 'PA3550BS', 'ASM353', 'PA353S', 'PA353SA', 'Price', 'date')
trecord = (1015, 'Mufaddal', True, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6050, '2022-01-22')
```

If you think my database schema is the problem itself please suggest any changes there as well.

Comment: The PROBLEM is that you are using `.format` to create your `INSERT` command.  That does not create proper SQL syntax, as you would see if you printed the formatted query.  You need to use`%s` substitution, just like you do in the `UPDATE` query above.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the INSERT query like this:

```
            trecord = tuple(record)
            vrecord = tuple(values)
            fields = ','.join(vrecord)
            values = ','.join(['%s']*len(trecord))
            query = f"INSERT INTO orders ({fields}) VALUES ({values})"
            print(vrecord)
            cursor.execute(query, trecord)  
            mydb.commit()
```

Comment: the same kind of error shows up :
```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id,name,Out,KSA4060,PAA003S,PAA003SS,Lapdesk,ASM704PH,LED4060,ASM820,ASM806,ASM8' at line 1
```

Comment: I forgot the parens around both substitutions.

Comment: I'm not exactly following. what does substitutions mean ?

Comment: Thank a lot worked like a charm, just changes the separator a little bit:
`fields = '`'+'`,`'.join(vrecord)+'`'`

Comment: You shouldn't need that, unless your column names unwisely have special characters.

Comment: Yeah- they have letters and numbers, but no spaces